# In Angular2/Typescript I want to load JSON data from a URL and bind to the Interface/Model

Tags: angular, angular-http

In Angular2/Typescript I want to load JSON data from a URL and bind to the Interface/Model. Sometime I want a single data object, other time I want to hold and array of the object.  Which one(Interface/Model) should I use and why?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the object you are getting back is exactly the same in both object versus array versions then I would always use the array version.

For example let's say the interface is

```
interface MyApiResponse {
  id: string;
  text: string;
}
```

In the case where you get an array you can return as is.
In the case where you get a single object just wrap it inside an array.

```
this.http.get(uri, options)
  .map(response => response.json()); 
  .map(data => {
    if (Array.isArray(data)) {
      return data;
    }

    return [data]
   });  // in both cases it will return back as MyApiResponse[]
```

Streamlining this as an array will simplify your application code as well.